# How can I teleport a player from a specific place to another in Minecraft Bedrock Edition using command blocks?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I'm making a multiplayer map, and I need to teleport a player from one place to another. However, I have all the command blocks set up at a separate area, so I cant just say /to @p [x y z]. Is there any way to teleport a player from one particular spot to another?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this `@a[x=~,y=~1,z=~,dx=0,dy=0,dz=0]` to target any player who is on top of the command block that is executing the command.

This command will teleport any player at the coordinates `100 50 100` to `150 60 150`:

```
/tp @a[x=100,y=50,z=100,dx=0,dy=0,dz=0] 150 60 150
```

Comment: I haven´t tested that command in the java edition, but it should work there, too

Answer (score 0):

If you wanna check for a specific block. Use this one:

```
execute @a ~ ~ ~ /testforblock ~ ~-1 ~ <name of block>
```

Then use a redstone comparator to activate the second command block which is using to teleport player around.